# Mac Chrome "Package Invalid Details: Could not load extension icon"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm running into an issue with my Chrome extension on OSX computers only.  It used to work fine, but with my latest release, I have a lot of files that I organized into folders (css, js, and img).  The extension installs just fine on Windows computers (which is the OS I created the extension on, Windows 7) but when I attempt to install on a Mac I get the message outlined below:
*"Package is invalid. Details: 'Could not load extension icon 'img\icon_16.png'.'.*
I know the image is there, but my guess is that because I did this on Windows, OSX doesn't like the pathing options.  Any ideas how I can rectify this and still keep the folder organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late, I'm aware, but the solution to this was the slash in img\, reversed it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that Google Play allows zip with .crx file.
So on first attempt it said me to zip my crx (after crx upload try), then it said that it needs manifest file inside the zip file. 
After that everything was fine except of extension installation - it threw out error like "Could not load extension icon".

So the solution is to compress src directory (in which manifest file lays) without packing extension into crx.